# Remove hyperlinks in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to load a html page through UIWebview.I need to disable all the hyperlinks in webview and make its color to normal text color i.e i need to disable webpage detection.Is that possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: i am using loadHTMLString function to load a html page .I need to show some string values in the webview ,so i created an html string using the <html> tag like <html>string</html>,also i used various font colors and formatting techniques for html.In the string value i am loading to the webview may contain web page links,i need to disable this .Please let me know whether it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this UIWebView method

```
– stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
```

To use Javascript.

Then use "*document.getElementsByTagName('a')*" to get an Array of elements and do want you want (change the href, change the color etc.)