# Disable UIWebView hyperlinks

Tags: ios

My goal is to allow UIWebView load initial link, but disallow any further navigation.

I saw question:

[Disable hyperlinks in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783074/disable-hyperlinks-in-uiwebview)

So, I wired referenced webView property from interface builder.

I specified that my UIViewController uses UIWebViewDelegate:

```
@interface LegalViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

In the code, on viewDidLoad, I do following:

```
 mFirstLoad = TRUE;
 webView.delegate = self;
```

And I have following code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (!mFirstLoad)
        return FALSE;

    mFirstLoad = FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

shouldStartLoadWithRequest is called both initial call and when I click on the link. However, even if shouldStartLoadWithRequest returns FALSE, UIWebView still proceeds and loads a new page.

I see this problem on iOS Simulator 6.0

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: are you sure the delegate method is being called?

Comment: Yes. I put a breakpoint in it and saw that it was hit (both for initial page load and after I click the link)

Comment: If you just put `return NO;` for all does it still load?

Comment: If I just return NO then it doesn't load initial page.

Comment: I think I found the reason for the problem. I am not sure how to properly call it (not a big expert on HTML and Javascript). However the link has following code : "<a href="/something" data-transition="flip">Something</a>" As result, callback is called, but it looks like results of this callback is ignored.

Comment: As result, most likely the answer for this question is in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880250/remove-hyperlinks-in-uiwebview?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same thing which I wrote in comments:

I think I found the reason for the problem. I am not sure how to properly call it (not a big expert on HTML and Javascript). However the link has following code : `"<a href="/something" data-transition="flip"</a>` As result, callback is called, but it looks like results of this callback is ignored.

As result most likely solution is here: [Remove hyperlinks in uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880250/remove-hyperlinks-in-uiwebview?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

return NO based on type to exclude links

return !(navigationTpe==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked);

Comment: Thanks. This will simplify my code a bit. However, it doesn't solve the main problem. even if I return NO/FALSE from shouldStartLoadWithRequest UIWebView still loads second page.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your boolean is getting reset somehow? What happens if you just return NO for `(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`?